# How can I improve a google-autocomplete response for a particular type?

Tags: javascript, api, google-places-autocomplete

Making a request to `Google-autocomplete` API is not returning me a precise response at the moment. For example, I have a case that if I try to search for 
'Bangkok Airport', it supposed to return me 'Suvarnabhumi airport', which is not, because it does not have enough words in common I suppose (even though inside the object that they return specifies the country which I make the research)

I can only find if I add a param called `radius=5000` & `location=latlng`(in bangkok) so then will find because it will restrict what's being researched for me.

I noticed that this happens with other results as well, does anyone knows a way for me to perhaps emphasize a certain type of result such as `airports`? Looking at the documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) they say that they only have a few types which they are not applicable for `airports` type. Will I have to implement something to manually translate? i.e: User types 'Bangkok Airport' and it changes to 'Suvarnabhumi airport' so it sends this request instead of the first? That seems a lot of work.

I have tried basically all params that are available from the docs

This is the current code of the params of my request:

```
request.open(
            "GET",
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?&input=" +
              encodeURIComponent(text) +
              "&" +
              Qs.stringify(this.props.query) +
              "&stricbounds" +
              "&location=" +
              this.props.lat +
              "," +
              this.props.lng +
              "&radius=5000," +
              "&types=administrative_area_level_2"
          );
```

I expect to be improving my response object coming from `google-autocomplete` api overall, when searching for `Bangkok airport` I want to output `Suvarnabhumi airport` and for other cases as well

Answer (score 0):

Upon trying your sample search on Query Autocomplete:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=Bangkok%20Airport&key=YOUR_API_KEY

I was able to get the specific airport in the predictions:
`Suvarnabhumi Airport (BKK), Soi Mu Ban Nakhon Thong 1, Nong Prue, Bang Phli District, Samut Prakan, Thailand` with Place ID `ChIJTydCFXdnHTERB3oVT1UZDRI`

[Query Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query) does not currently support filter for a specific type such as `airports`.

If it fits your use-case, you can also use [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) with this sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Bangkok%20Airport&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

There is an existing feature request for this to filter for specific types:
    https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

We recommend for you comment your use-case in there or star it to receive updates.